# LWJGL Sound manager issue

Tags: lwjgl

I have been working on the Asteroids Game example code that they give in the tutorials section of the wiki and I ran into a strange error.

The code works just fine in my development environment, Eclipse. The game runs without error and exits normally.

I go through the export process in the file menu and create an executable jar that when run with this batch file code

```
java -Djava.library.path=D:\Tools\lwjgl-2.8.4\lwjgl-2.8.4\native\windows -jar SpaceInvaders.jar
```

Starts the display and the fails when it trys to load a wav file. Giving this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I traced to where in the code this is happening and it is at the location where the wavs are being loaded. Apprently outside of the environment it can't locate the files even though they are right next to the code? All my wav files and gif files are just in the same directory as the java class files right now so calling them from the code looks likes this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlNm8.png

Searching for stuff on google it tells me to zip them into a seperate file and then import to the class folder and refrence from there. I was wondering if there was a way to keep the files inside my main jar file instead of having to create a seperate entity.

Thanks for the replys! Let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using a higher-level API, such as [the 3d soundsystem from paulscode](http://www.paulscode.com/forum/index.php?topic=4.0).  SoundSystem can read from inside the jar(like you are asking), and automatically switch to java sound if LWJGL sound isn't supported on the current hardware.